# Find the line & edit it

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, edit, text-files, lines

I posted another one on this,, but i had to edit it really much...

What the thing bassicly is that a Batch (Maybe including VBScript) can find line 29 in a txtfile... it should edit this line.

If line 29 is like this: 'option=21'   it should change it to 'option=22'

the problem is that this line is located more in the file. so it should just edit line 29...

How-to???

[please no custom programs;;; it should be done by every user without installing something OK.]

Comment: Can't you push this through gpo or something when the user logged in?  Or it's not an ideal situation for that either?  Basically, copy the file w/ the correct text from a common network share and overwrite the file on the user computer wherever this particular file is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something you're usually doing in batch, but it's fairly straightforward:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem the input file
set inputfile=file.txt

rem temporary file for output, we can't just write into the
rem same file we're reading
set tempfile=%random%-%random%.tmp

rem delete the temporary file if it's already there
rem shouldn't really happen, but just in case ...
copy /y nul %tempfile%

rem line counter
set line=0

rem loop through the file
for /f "delims=" %%l in (%inputfile%) do (
    set /a line+=1
    if !line!==29 (
        rem hardcoded, at the moment, you might want to look
        rem here whether the line really starts with "options"
        rem and just put another number at the end.
        echo option=22>>%tempfile%
    ) else (
        echo %%l>>%tempfile%
    )
)

del %inputfile%
ren %tempfile% %inputfile%

endlocal
```

It should point you into the general direction if you want to adapt it.

Comment: yeah what the problem was; 'option=22' should be changed into '<option=22>'. I kinda found out that it should be like this: '^<option=22^>'

Comment: I have searched for this forever.....thankyou!!! I wish I could give you all my bounty because I can't tell you how long I have tried for this.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are asking for a `vb` script,
Using `AWK`, it would go something like this,
maybe it will help you code `vb`.

awk '{if(FNR==29) {gsub(/option=21/,"option=22"); print} else {print $0;}}' input.txt > output.txt

Have not tried it, so might have some mild glitches...

1. the `FNR=29` will check for processing `gsub` only on line 29

   - `gsub` will replace any `option=21` occurrences on the line with `option=22`
   - other lines will be passed through

Comment: Yes, i just fixed some of the errors i caught visually. Want to just describe the scheme; which I am sure can be done with VB too.

Comment: the awk command can be shortened : gawk "FNR==29{gsub(/option=21/,\"option=22\")}1" file.txt

Answer (score 0):

here's a vbscript

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "c:\test\file.txt"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    linenum = objFile.Line
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If linenum = 29 Then
        strLine = Replace(strLine,"option=21","option=22")
    End If
    WScript.Echo strLine
Loop
```

how to use:

```
c:\test> cscript /nologo myscript.vbs > newfile
c:\test> ren newfile file.txt
```